# XSLT - Why are multiple nodes getting merged in the output ( Group By)

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

All-
I am trying to understand the root cause for 2 nodes getting merged.

## The input XML

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<Employees>
    <Employee>
        <Employee_ID>E00001</Employee_ID>
        <Legal_Name Descriptor="John Doe" />         
        <lastName>Doe</lastName>
        <firstName>John</firstName>
        <P_From_Date>2015-04-01-08:00</P_From_Date>
        <P_End_Date>2015-12-31-08:00</P_End_Date>

        <Transaction>            
            <Plan Descriptor="Plan A" />            
            <effective_date>2015-03-22-08:00</effective_date>
                    <end_date>2015-10-22</end_date>
            <Annual_Cost>6000</Annual_Cost>
        </Transaction>

        <Transaction>            
            <Plan Descriptor="Plan A" />            
            <effective_date>2015-02-03-08:00</effective_date>
            <Annual_Cost>4000</Annual_Cost>
        </Transaction>

        <Transaction>            
            <Plan Descriptor="Plan A" />            
            <effective_date>2013-02-03-08:00</effective_date>
            <Annual_Cost>3000</Annual_Cost>
        </Transaction>


        <Transaction>            
            <Plan Descriptor="Plan B" />            
            <effective_date>2014-12-03-08:00</effective_date>
            <Annual_Cost>12000</Annual_Cost>
        </Transaction>  

        <Transaction>            
            <Plan Descriptor="Plan B" />            
            <effective_date>2014-10-03-08:00</effective_date>
            <Annual_Cost>1000</Annual_Cost>
        </Transaction>  

   </Employee>       

     <Employee>
        <Employee_ID>E00002</Employee_ID>
        <Legal_Name Descriptor="John Doe" />         
        <lastName>Test</lastName>
        <firstName>Jane</firstName>
        <P_From_Date>2015-01-01-08:00</P_From_Date>

        <Transaction>            
            <Plan Descriptor="Plan D" />            
            <effective_date>2015-05-22-08:00</effective_date>
            <Annual_Cost>12000</Annual_Cost>
        </Transaction>

        <Transaction>            
            <Plan Descriptor="Plan D" />            
            <effective_date>2014-03-01-08:00</effective_date>
            <Annual_Cost>9000</Annual_Cost>
        </Transaction>

        <Transaction>            
            <Plan Descriptor="Plan C" />            
            <effective_date>2014-12-03-08:00</effective_date>
            <Annual_Cost>3000</Annual_Cost>
        </Transaction>


        <Transaction>            
            <Plan Descriptor="Plan C" />            
            <effective_date>2013-01-03-08:00</effective_date>
            <Annual_Cost>3000</Annual_Cost>
        </Transaction>


     </Employee>     
</Employees>
```

## And the XSLT

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"

    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml"/>
    <!-- TODO customize transformation rules 
         syntax recommendation http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt 
    -->
    <xsl:variable name="newline" select="'&#xd;'"/>
    <xsl:variable name="delimiter">,</xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="qualifier">
        <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:template match="/Employees">
        <EES>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </EES>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Employee">

        <EE>

        <EID>
        <xsl:value-of select="Employee_ID" />
        </EID>        

        <FULNAME>
        <xsl:value-of select="Legal_Name/@Descriptor"/>
        </FULNAME>
        <LNAME>
        <xsl:value-of select="lastName"/>
        </LNAME>        
        <FNAME>
        <xsl:value-of select="firstName"/>
        </FNAME>


        <xsl:variable name="bework">
            <xsl:for-each-group select="Transaction" group-by="Plan/@Descriptor" >
                <berow>
                    <CurrentGroup>
                        <xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key()"/>
                    </CurrentGroup>
                    <parm_from_date><xsl:value-of select="../P_From_Date" /></parm_from_date>
                    <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
                        <begin-date><xsl:copy-of select="effective_date" /></begin-date>

                        <include-flag >
                            <xsl:choose>
                                <xsl:when test="xs:date( substring(effective_date,1,10)) &gt;=  xs:date(substring(../P_From_Date,1,10))">
                                    <xsl:text>Y</xsl:text>
                                </xsl:when>
                                <xsl:otherwise>
                                    <xsl:text>N</xsl:text>
                                </xsl:otherwise>
                            </xsl:choose>

                        </include-flag>
                        <adj-begin-date>
                            <xsl:choose>
                                <xsl:when test="xs:date(effective_date) &gt;= xs:date(../P_From_Date_1) ">
                                    <xsl:value-of select="effective_date"/>
                                </xsl:when>
                                <xsl:otherwise>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="../P_From_Date_1"/>
                                </xsl:otherwise>
                             </xsl:choose>
                        </adj-begin-date>
                        <end_date>
                            <xsl:value-of select="current-group()/end_date"/>
                        </end_date>
                        <Cost>
                            <xsl:value-of select="Annual_Cost"/>
                        </Cost>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </berow>
            </xsl:for-each-group>
        </xsl:variable>

        <xsl:for-each select="$bework/berow">


            <CGR>
            <xsl:value-of select="CurrentGroup" />
            </CGR>



            <PFRMDT>            
            <xsl:value-of select="parm_from_date" />
            </PFRMDT>


            <BDT>
            <xsl:value-of select="begin-date" />
            </BDT>


            <FLAG>
            <xsl:value-of select="include-flag" />
            </FLAG>


            <ADJBGNDT>
            <xsl:value-of select="$qualifier"/>
            </ADJBGNDT>


            <EDATE>            
            <xsl:value-of select="$qualifier"/>
            </EDATE>

            <CO>
            <xsl:value-of select="Cost" />                        
            </CO>


        </xsl:for-each>

        </EE>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The result

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<EES xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <EE>
        <EID>E00001</EID>
        <FULNAME>John Doe</FULNAME>
        <LNAME>Doe</LNAME>
        <FNAME>John</FNAME>
        <CGR>Plan A</CGR>
        <PFRMDT>2015-04-01-08:00</PFRMDT>
        <BDT>2015-03-22-08:00 2015-02-03-08:00 2013-02-03-08:00</BDT>
        <FLAG>N N N</FLAG>
        <ADJBGNDT>"</ADJBGNDT>
        <EDATE>"</EDATE>
        <CO>6000 4000 3000</CO>
        <CGR>Plan B</CGR>
        <PFRMDT>2015-04-01-08:00</PFRMDT>
        <BDT>2014-12-03-08:00 2014-10-03-08:00</BDT>
        <FLAG>N N</FLAG>
        <ADJBGNDT>"</ADJBGNDT>
        <EDATE>"</EDATE>
        <CO>12000 1000</CO>
    </EE>        

    <EE>
        <EID>E00002</EID>
        <FULNAME>John Doe</FULNAME>
        <LNAME>Test</LNAME>
        <FNAME>Jane</FNAME>
        <CGR>Plan D</CGR>
        <PFRMDT>2015-01-01-08:00</PFRMDT>
        <BDT>2015-05-22-08:00 2014-03-01-08:00</BDT>
        <FLAG>Y N</FLAG>
        <ADJBGNDT>"</ADJBGNDT>
        <EDATE>"</EDATE>
        <CO>12000 9000</CO>
        <CGR>Plan C</CGR>
        <PFRMDT>2015-01-01-08:00</PFRMDT>
        <BDT>2014-12-03-08:00 2013-01-03-08:00</BDT>
        <FLAG>N N</FLAG>
        <ADJBGNDT>"</ADJBGNDT>
        <EDATE>"</EDATE>
        <CO>3000 3000</CO>
    </EE>    
</EES>
```

If you look at John Doe's BDT node, there are 2 dates. These are 2 nodes for the sample plan are getting added to the same node despite looping through the current group.

WHat is causing this? And what should be done to remedy this? I will have to use variables as there is more manulations I will have to do. But that is for another day.

Thanks for providng me some insight.

Comment: What is the desired result?

Comment: You are grouping by `Plan/@Descriptor` ; since I see three times the value *Plan A* (for example), it seems normal that you will retrieve the 3 other elements in output (name the `effective_date`), even if the key "found" once.

Comment: @potame - Yes, I am grouping by Plan descriptor. But after grouping, I am loping through each group and adding the BDT element.This is in the variable <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">  I am grouping (and will have to eventually sort by plan descriptor and the effective date. But tryign to get my variable right.

Comment: @Ivan I am trying to bring all the transactions for the same plan together(adjascent)  i am trying to follow this example [link]http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2003/11/05/tr.html The only difference is that I am writing to the variable rather than the output and then writing to the output(just to verify what I have is correct. My final result is more involved and hence using a varable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside of your `bework` variable you create a `berow` element for each `Transaction` group but then you use `<xsl:for-each select="current-group()">` to output a `begin-date` for each `Transaction` in that group, without structuring or wrapping them further. With your input that means that `berow` element can contain two or three `begin-date` elements.

Then you have `<xsl:for-each select="$bework/berow">` and inside

```
        <BDT>
        <xsl:value-of select="begin-date" />
        </BDT>
```

which will select and output the string value of the two or three `begin-date` elements.

I am not sure which value you want to output for `BDT`, you could use e.g. `<xsl:value-of select="begin-date[1]"/>` or `<xsl:value-of select="begin-date[last()]"/>` to output only the string value of the first or last element created earlier.

Comment: My intention in this pass is to get all specific benefit plans together and then output nodes. But looks like my understanding of what looping thought current-group() in a for-each is incorrect.  How do I loop through the nodes in current group and spit out the nodes? I need to spit out all the nodes.

Comment: I am trying to replicate something like this [link]http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2003/11/05/tr.html  The only difference is I am writing to a variable first and then outputting the elements from the variable. I am writing to the output from the variable to verify the results.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you just need to change:

```
<BDT>
<xsl:value-of select="begin-date" />
</BDT>
```

to:

```
<BDT>
<xsl:copy-of select="begin-date" />
</BDT>
```

In XSLT 2.0, `xsl:value-of` will generate a *single* text node, concatenating the values of all matching nodes, separated by a space (or another separator, if specified).

---

### Additional explanation:

> WHat is causing this?

The reason why your nodes are getting merged into a single text node is that you are using `xsl:value-of` when you try to fetch them from the $bework variable in order to write them into the output tree.

Consider the following simplified example:

**XML**

```
<root>
    <item>
        <category>A</category>
        <amount>1000</amount>
    </item>
    <item>
        <category>A</category>
        <amount>500</amount>
    </item>
    <item>
        <category>A</category>
        <amount>250</amount>
    </item>
    <item>
        <category>B</category>
        <amount>600</amount>
    </item>
    <item>
        <category>B</category>
        <amount>300</amount>
    </item>
</root>
```

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <xsl:variable name="groups">
        <xsl:for-each-group select="item" group-by="category">
            <group category="{current-grouping-key()}">
                <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
                    <amount>
                        <xsl:value-of select="amount"/>
                    </amount>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </group>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:variable>
    <output>    
        <xsl:for-each select="$groups/group">
            <group category="{@category}">
                <copy-of-amount>    
                    <xsl:copy-of select="amount"/>
                </copy-of-amount>       
                <for-each-amount>   
                    <xsl:for-each select="amount">
                        <new-node value="{.}"/>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </for-each-amount>      
                <sum-of-amount> 
                    <xsl:value-of select="sum(amount)"/>
                </sum-of-amount>        
                <value-of-amount>   
                    <xsl:value-of select="amount"/>
                </value-of-amount>      
            </group>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </output>       
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<output>
   <group category="A">
      <copy-of-amount>
         <amount>1000</amount>
         <amount>500</amount>
         <amount>250</amount>
      </copy-of-amount>
      <for-each-amount>
         <new-node value="1000"/>
         <new-node value="500"/>
         <new-node value="250"/>
      </for-each-amount>
      <sum-of-amount>1750</sum-of-amount>
      <value-of-amount>1000 500 250</value-of-amount>
   </group>
   <group category="B">
      <copy-of-amount>
         <amount>600</amount>
         <amount>300</amount>
      </copy-of-amount>
      <for-each-amount>
         <new-node value="600"/>
         <new-node value="300"/>
      </for-each-amount>
      <sum-of-amount>900</sum-of-amount>
      <value-of-amount>600 300</value-of-amount>
   </group>
</output>
```

As you can see, inside the `$myVar` variable, each `group` contains 2-3 distinct `amount` nodes. You can copy them, sum them or create something for each one of them. However, when you do:

```
<xsl:value-of select="amount"/>
```

you are addressing **all** the amount nodes in the current group, and you will get a result that incorporates them all, same as:

```
<xsl:value-of select="sum(amount)"/>
```

returns a result based on all the amount nodes being addressed.

> And what should be done to remedy this?

We won't know that until you tell us what is the actual result you want to get. In the comments below you said that:

> the final result is really the total cost per employee.

If so, the example above shows how to get it.

Comment: Why do we need to do that ? I am trying to accomplish the same thing in the example here [link]http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2003/11/05/tr.html

Comment: Please edit your question and post your expected result.

Comment: @michaelr hor257k  I am struggling to figure out what I should pose as the final result is really the total cost per employee. But there are a few rules that need to be honored.

Comment: In the meantime, can I ask you a question on the for-each group functionality ? I am initially invoking the following `for-each-group select="Transaction" group-by="Plan/@Descriptor"` and then calling `xsl:for-each select="current-group()"`. My understanding(which may be incorrect) is that he first for-each-group groups all the transaction nodes into multiple groups based on the @Descriptor attribute.  And the call to for-each passing the current-group() should loop through each transaction node belonging to the current group().

Comment: Thus I would expect for E01 for Plan A to loop through each Transaction node for Plan A initially and  create as many nodes for the data elements. Thus , I was expecting 4 nodes for each of the children of the Transaction Node.

Comment: @StillStumbling Your understanding is essentially correct. However, you are putting these 4 nodes in a variable first. Later, when you call for the `value-of` the variable's nodes, you are getting all the 4 values mashed together into a single text node. I have added a more detailed explanation to my answer.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. One more question.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. One more question.  Like the amount, I might need to reference other fields that are children of the same Transaction node. For e.g. amount and  effective date,  Both are related and hence, I need to keep those 2 nodes together. In your explanation, it almost seems that I need to loop through each child node separately. `<xsl:for-each select="amount">` I do not want to lose the relationship between the effective date and the amount. Is that doable? Sorry for the delay in responding. :(

Comment: I am not sure I understand your question. What does "*keep those 2 nodes together*" mean? Usually, you keep nodes "together" by putting them inside a common parent node. You already have that in the source document - so all you need to do is create a new node (or copy the existing one)  for each Transaction in the current group, and place the two child nodes inside it.

Comment: In the example each amount/aka annual cost is associated with a specific effective date in a transaction. So something like this - `<xtn>><effdate></effdate><amount></amount></xtn>` is what I ma hoping to gett off the variable.This is with reference to my input document. I posted a different question which what I really need. (The input has changed on me) I tried to  provide all details and the final output expected. Will forward that post to you and also reference it here

Comment: I am sorry, I have completely lost track of what this is about. Is not your original question answered?

Comment: Link to new post - [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30082261/how-do-i-derive-the-total-cost-in-xslt/30082363#30082363

Comment: I will flag this as answered. I will have to play around with this one. I created a new question as the format of input changed on me. I have tried to provide additional information and the final output expected rather.